# Using both Google Analytics and Chartbeart

Tags: google-analytics

I'm thinking of trying out Chartbeat. I want to keep the Analytics code in there. Is there a noticable impact on performance for the visitor if both are used?

Comment: You may want to check out the new Realtime feature in Google Analytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the code at the bottom of your page, just before the `</body>` tag, I don't think you will notice much if any performance impact.